# How to fix a CSV read error with a semicolon at line end

Tags: ruby, csv

I want to use Ruby's CSV class to read a file:

The file to read looks like:

```
CM_ SG_ 1325 XXX_Address "XXX address";
CM_ SG_ 612 YYY_MsgCounter "incremented by 1 each time a 
message has been transmitted";
```

My ruby code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'pp'
require 'csv'
CSV.foreach(ARGV[0],:col_sep=>" ") do |row|
    pp row
end
```

This is the error I get:

```
C:/ruby-2.3.3-x64-mingw32/lib/ruby/2.3.0/csv.rb:1898:in `block in shift': Unclosed quoted field on l
ine 1. (CSV::MalformedCSVError)
        from C:/ruby-2.3.3-x64-mingw32/lib/ruby/2.3.0/csv.rb:1805:in `loop'
        from C:/ruby-2.3.3-x64-mingw32/lib/ruby/2.3.0/csv.rb:1805:in `shift'
        from C:/ruby-2.3.3-x64-mingw32/lib/ruby/2.3.0/csv.rb:1747:in `each'
        from C:/ruby-2.3.3-x64-mingw32/lib/ruby/2.3.0/csv.rb:1131:in `block in foreach'
        from C:/ruby-2.3.3-x64-mingw32/lib/ruby/2.3.0/csv.rb:1282:in `open'
        from C:/ruby-2.3.3-x64-mingw32/lib/ruby/2.3.0/csv.rb:1130:in `foreach'
        from test.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

If I remove the semicolons at the end of the lines, I get this:

```
["CM_", "SG_", "1325", "XXX_Address", "XXX address"]
["CM_",
 "SG_",
 "612",
 "YYY_MsgCounter",
 "incremented by 1 each time a \r\nmessage has been transmitted"]
```

which is what I would expect to see.

I'm assuming the problem is that CSV doesn't like the semicolon up against the quote. Is there a way to chomp that semicolon off using a CSV option or give CSV a stream where I've already chomp'd it off?

**Clarifications:**

I apologize for not specifying this originally, *but not every line will have a semicolon*.

Also, I would like to thank Tin Man for making superfluous edits to my post to increase his score. ;)

Comment: In your file is this across two lines? "incremented by 1 each time a 
message has been transmitted"

Comment: Yes Sara, there is a newline in the quoted string.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know each row ends with a semicolon then just specify the row separator e.g.

```
CSV.foreach(ARGV[0],col_sep:" ", row_sep:";").to_a
#=> [["CM_", "SG_", "1325", "XXX_Address", "XXX address"], 
#    ["CM_", "SG_", "612", "YYY_MsgCounter", "incremented by 1 each time a message has been transmitted"]]
```

You will lose the new line in the row not sure how important that is though

**NOTE as per my discussion with @iGian this solution is for ruby < 2.6.0 and his solution is for >= 2.6.0**

Comment: I apologize for not specifying this originally, but not every line will have a semicolon.

Comment: @oaklodge given that this does not appear to truly be a CSV and the line endings have no standard I am not sure exactly where to go from here. In theory you could strip all the semicolons and pass the resulting string to `CSV.parse` but I am unsure how large this file is an how intensive that might be for you. Maybe give this a try? `CSV.parse(File.read(ARGV[0]).gsub(';',''), col_sep: ' ')`

Comment: I gravitated to CSV because it did the important job of splitting while respecting quoted elements. I will try your solution when I'm in front of my computer again. I might cheat and create a temp file chomped of trailing semicolons.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, **for Ruby 2.6.1**:

```
require 'pp'
require 'csv'

CSV.foreach(ARGV[0], col_sep: ' ', row_sep: :auto, liberal_parsing: {double_quote_outside_quote: true} ) do |row|
    pp row
end
```

It seems to work. See this issue: https://github.com/ruby/csv/issues/66

Comment: Did you test that because it doesn't work for me and it does not seem to pertain to this situation since there are no double double quoted strings

Comment: @engineersmnky, yes I did and it works in my environment (Ruby 2.6.1). I first tested the exact solution you posted and I got `TODO: Meaningful message in line 2. (CSV::MalformedCSVError)`. When I use `;` instead of `:auto` I get `Do not allow except col_sep_split_separator after quoted fields in line 1`. But I now realise it is due to Ruby version. I'm going to edit.

Comment: that is strange I can confirm your findings in `2.6.1` however in < `2.6` (tested `2.5.1`, `2.3.3`, `2.1.5`,`1.9.3`)  mine works as described below. And I really love the meaningful message :)

Comment: Side note just `liberal_parsing: {}` works too seems just the key has to be present in options

Comment: @engineersmnky, fresh installed 2.6.3 and got the same issue as 2.6.1. Do you?

Comment: it appears to be a change in 2.6 that causes my code to fail. Unfortuantely the OP is using 2.3.3 and has stated that not all lines end with semicolons so it just seems like the CSV itself is malformed and since the "liberal parsing" is not part of < 2.6 I am not sure how to help from here.